# How do you create an array of binary search trees?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, binary-search-tree

If I have a class for BST, would I do something like `array = new BST[size]` in order to create an array of BST's?
Additionally, if I did end up creating an array, what would each element in the array be when it's first created?

Comment: no. you never do `new anything` in user code. You would do `std::vector<BST>` or `std::array<BST, size>`.

Comment: Note that with `std::vector<BST>` you can start with an empty vector and add BSTs when you have them constructed. You can also create a vector with N default constructed BSTs or provide a BST used to initialize the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Yes that would create an array, but as already said you should prefer

```
vector<BST> array(size);
```

Either way the BSTs would be default initialised. So whatever your BST default constructor does, that's what the BSTs will be.

Answer (score 0):

Following code snippet may help you to understand BST Class in C++:

```
// C++ program to demonstrate insertion
// in a BST recursively.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class BST {
    int data;
    BST *left, *right;
 
public:
    // Default constructor.
    BST(){
      
 
    // Parameterized constructor.
    BST(int);
 
    // Insert function.
    BST* Insert(BST*, int);
 
    // Inorder traversal.
    void Inorder(BST*);
};

// Driver code
int main()
{
    //Create array of BST:
    vectot<*BST> bstArr(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        bstArr[i] = new BST();
    }
    
    //use bst array.
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please note that the question was _not_ about how to create a BST, but rather about how to create an _array_ of BSTs.  Could you edit your answer to show that?  Otherwise it does not help the original questioner.  Or if it does not add anything to existing answers, maybe it should not be kept.

Comment: And that's a bad definition of a BST since it can't represent the empty tree.

Comment: Modified comment to show how array of bst pointers can be created